# Why would running rsync cause the Date Modified value on a particular folder on the source volume to change?

Tags: finder, macos, backup, rsync

I ran rsync last night to backup some of my drive. When I woke up, the source folder (which is sorted by Date Modified, descending) had a particular sub-folder at the top which I haven't touched in months. I opened it and there was one sub-folder within that also had an updated Date Modified value. And another and another and then in that folder there were more folders, but none of those had an updated Date Modified value, so that's where the trail went cold. Could rsync have modified or deleted a file or a hidden file? And why this folder only?

Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6 (16G1815)

This was my command line entry:

```
rsync -vrlHpogt /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Stuff /Volumes/My\ Backup\ sparseimage/
```

Comment: What was the exact command line call of rsync and did any of the changed files have any metadata

Comment: @Mark Thanks. Edited question to include the rsync line.

Comment: Note the spaces in the destination directory name are not escaped.

Comment: Thanks @fd0 for the note. That was a typo. Fixed.